# Get base URL from Axios - react native

Tags: react-native, axios

Is is possible to get the base URL from the axios and store it to a variable?

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://192.168.0.103/api",
});
```

What i want to do is..

```
const photo= "HTTP://192.168.0.103/" + image-Path;
```

this is working , but i don't want to use the address here (since i already declared it in axios file, i don't want to repeat it several pages), instead i want to get it from axios and use it here.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work

```
    const axios = require('axios');

    const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://www.google.com.pk"
    });

    console.log(api.defaults.baseURL)
```